# A Wild, Wicked Slip

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, nineteenth-century-english

From *Wuthering Heights* by Emily Brontë:

> A wild, wicked slip she was—but she had the bonniest eye, the sweetest smile, and lightest foot in the parish […]

What does "slip" mean?

Comment: A slight young woman.

Comment: I think the opening phrase is a great bit of writing.  In the 2010 retelling *[Wuthering Bites](https://books.google.com/books?id=s5OWBgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA45&dq=%22A%20wild%2C%20wicked%20slip%20she%20was%2C%20and%20as%20daring%20as%20the%20devil%20himself%22&pg=PA45#v=onepage&q=%22A%20wild,%20wicked%20slip%20she%20was%22&f=false)* it appeared as "A wild, wicked slip she was, and as daring as the devil himself, but she had the bonniest eyes and the sweetest smile."  I admit this comment veers off topic, but I wanted to voice my appreciation for Brontë's turn of phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=slip):

> "sprig or twig for planting or grafting, small shoot," late 15c., of uncertain origin. Compare Middle Dutch slippe, German schlippe, schlipfe "cut, slit, strip." Hence "young person of small build" (1580s, as in a **slip of a girl**); see slip (n.1).